# Universal Language Dictionary

Tags: python, data-structures

I want to create an efficient data structure that scales such that given two translations, say, (Hello, English, German, Hallo) and  (German, Hallo, French, Bonjour,) I'm able to quickly retrieve, How to say Hello, English in French. And also, if I only know Hallo, German, I'm able to retrieve it English through get_translation(hallo, german, english), despite the input mapping I provided only being from English to German and not vice-versa.

so given inputs (lang1, word1, lang2, word2) and (lang2, word2, lang3, word3) , the function will quickly return for args (lang1, word1, lang3) --> word3, despite us not having created the mapping for the word from lang1 to lang3.

What kind of hash map, graph hybrid could possible make for the cleanest solution here? I'm trying both be able to traverse a graph, and preserver O(1) look up.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd recommend you to use just a [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for now. It's O(1) and Python is supper optimized around it.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
{"hello":{"german":"hallo", "french": "bonjour"}}
```

Comment: Should've specified - I'm looking for a scalable solution, whereby if I have a input a translation from lang1 to lang2, and lang2 to lang3, I should be able to retrieve translation from lang1 to lang3 without explicitly writing it out. I want to traverse a graph.

Seems like you've hardcoded it here. I also want to be able to have (German, 'hallo', English) return Hello.

Comment: @juan-mendoza Please specify a bit more about your structure in the question by editing it.

Comment: Allow me to point out that this approach won't work in the real world, though maybe you're not bothered by that. Threre is not in general a language-independent 1:1 relationship between words in different languages and abstract concepts. For example, the English  word *driver* may be translated several ways in Dutch,  depending on what is being driven: *machinist* (train), *bestuurder* (tram), *chauffeur* (bus), *automobilist* (private car).

Comment: Agreed that there are real world limitations. But we can restrict this to well-defined, roughly universal concepts, like 'Hello', 'Chair', 'Mother', etc.